# BringIntoView Method

Tags: c#, wpf, alignment, scrollview, vertical-alignment

In WPF, I have a scrollviewer with 7 different groupboxes in it.  Each groupbox is it's own individual section for different forms.  Because the scrollviewer is so long, I've placed a series of buttons in a stackpanel on the left side of the panel, and done code-behind so that clicking a button triggers the BringIntoView method for the corresponding groupbox.

My question is, is there any way to force BringIntoView to position the groupbox at the top of the visible section each time.  By default BringIntoView only moves the scrollviewer until the entire groupbox is within view, not so that it's the topmost item displayed.  Is there a way around this?

I looked into using ScrollToVerticalOffset, but couldn't figure out how to get the right position, mostly because it's saying that groupbox has no Locate property, which I was going to use to get the position, then set it with ScrollToVerticalOffset.  One thing I thought of while typing this was to have each button-press jusmp to the top groupbox first, then immediately continue to the correct one, but this seems kind of hack-ish, and I prefer to find the correct way. :)

Comment: Just a word of advice, how about a bit less code and breaking up that first paragraph into smaller more digestible paragraphs. Otherwise we just have a wall of text and a wall of code which won't attract much attention and will put folks off. Have a read of Jon Skeets excellent post on how to ask the perfect question here: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this one:

```
private void ScrollToGroupBox(GroupBox groupBox)
{
  GeneralTransform groupBoxTransform = groupBox.TransformToAncestor(scrollViewer);
  Rect rectangle = groupBoxTransform.TransformBounds(new Rect(new Point(0, 0), groupBox.RenderSize));
  scrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(rectangle.Top + scrollViewer.VerticalOffset);
}
```

The code gets the position of your GroupBox inside the Scrollviewer and scrolls to it.

Comment: Works great!  Now my only issue is leaving enough room at the bottom to still allow the final GroupBox to reach the top before it runs out of room.  I did this by adding a margin to the bottom of the final GroupBox, but if you know of a better way I'd love to hear it.  It works how I have it, but if I resize the window to be taller it doesn't quite reach.

Comment: Glad I could help. I don't know of a better way but adding a Margin or setting the groupbox height to the same value as the scrollviewer.
You could do this by binding the height of the last groupbox in the scrollviewer by following xaml code:
<GroupBox Height="{Binding Path=ActualHeight,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ScrollViewer}}}"  ... />